# php beginner: handling array in Joomla module

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, beginner

Newbie in php, I am trying to create a module to extract orders from Joomla database and plot monthly results as a yearly curve.
I am trying to store first the products in an array, followed by a monthly number of orders.

Database extraction is ok and I created a first array containing the product names and for each product, I'd like to create an array containing its 12 monthly quantities.

I created the product names array as below:

```
foreach ($products as $pr)
    $results[] = $pr->name;
```

and the quantities array in the products loop as below:

```
foreach ($quantities as $quant) 
    $quant_array[] = $quant->number;
```

Now, how can I merge those two arrays (and also how to read data afterwards) so that the results looks like

```
prod_A-->1
         1
         2
       ...
prod_B-->2
         3
         5
       ...
prod_C-->3
         4
         2
       ...
```

Helper code is herebelow, obviously not finished:

```
public static function getProduits($params)
        {
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $userId = (int) $user->get('id');
        
        // Obtain a database connection
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query="select `name` as prodname, product_id from #__jshopping_products where product_publish=1 order by `name`";
        // Prepare the query
        $db->setQuery($query);
        // Loading products.
        $prod = $db->loadObjectList();
        
        foreach ($prod as $pr)
            {
            $results[] = $pr->prodname;

            $query2 = "SELECT count(product_quantity) as number, month(#__jshopping_orders.order_date) as month from #__jshopping_order_item join #__jshopping_orders on #__jshopping_orders.order_id=#__jshopping_order_item.order_id " .
                      "where #__jshopping_order_item.order_id in (select order_id FROM #__jshopping_orders where user_id=" . $userId . " and year(#__jshopping_orders.order_date)=2022 order by order_date desc) " .
                      "and product_id=" . $pr->product_id . " group by month(order_date) order by month(order_date) desc";

            // Prepare the query
            $db->setQuery($query2);
            // Loading data
            $amounts = $db->loadObjectList();

            foreach ($amounts as $quant) 
                $quant_array[] = $quant->number;    
            }
            
            **/// This is where I'd like to merge results within one array ($results)
            // like $results['product']['count']**
        
        return ($results);
        }
}
```

$results being passed to the template file for output

It is probably a trivial task but as I said, I am a php beginner...

Thank you!

---

Revisiting this question, I succeeded creating a single query to achieve this.
When I test results within the helper file with echo statements, it displays ok.
However, when I try to get the values in the **default.php** output template file, I just get nothing, meaning that I probably have an issue with either the variable return or something else which I don't see, being a real php newbie...

Here's how I declared my module entry point:

```
<?php
// No direct access defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
global $prod;
$prod = modProduitsHelper::getProduits($params);
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_produits');
?>
```

I know I should not use a global declaration but I tried :-)

Helper file is ok and looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Helper class for module stats
 */
class modProduitsHelper
{
/**
 *
 * @param   array  $params An object containing the module parameters
 *
 * @access public
 */    
    public static function getProduits($params)
        {
        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        $userId = (int) $user->get('id');
        
        // Obtain a database connection
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query="SELECT
              product_name as nom,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 1, product_quantity, 0)) as Janv,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 2, product_quantity, 0)) as Feb,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 3, product_quantity, 0)) as Mar,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 4, product_quantity, 0)) as Apr,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 5, product_quantity, 0)) as May,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 6, product_quantity, 0)) as Jun,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 7, product_quantity, 0)) as Jul,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 8, product_quantity, 0)) as Aug,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 9, product_quantity, 0)) as Sep,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 10, product_quantity, 0)) as Oct,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 11, product_quantity, 0)) as Nov,
              sum(if(month(order_date) = 12, product_quantity, 0)) as `Dec`
            FROM vpkbb_jshopping_order_item join vpkbb_jshopping_orders on vpkbb_jshopping_orders.order_id=vpkbb_jshopping_order_item.order_id  
            WHERE user_id = 398
            AND year(order_date) = 2022
            group by product_name
            order by product_name;";
        // Prepare the query
        $db->setQuery($query);
        // Chargement des produits.
        $prod = $db->loadObjectList();
        
        return ($prod);
        }
}?>
```

and, finally, my default.php template file looks for now just like this:

```
<?php 
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;   

foreach ($prod as $pr)
    echo $pr->nom . ' ' . $pr->Jan . ' ' . $pr->Feb . ' ' . $pr->Mar . ' ' . $pr->Apr . ' ' . $pr->May . ' ' . $pr->Jun . ' ' . $pr->Jul . ' ' . $pr->Aug . ' ' . $pr->Sep . ' ' . $pr->Oct . ' ' . $pr->Nov . ' ' . $pr->Dec . '<br />';?>
```

I thought I had my Xmas present, but it looks like I don't, so if anybody could point me to what I do wrong, this would save this miserable attempt to achieve my goal.

Thx

Comment: Perhaps you may use a query that combine in one array all the information you need. I mean if you need to list all products in your database, you may use LEFT JOIN using #__jshopping_products as first table and then adding constraints from your query2. In case that you only need data from sold products, you could simply use an inner join with product_id as key.

Comment: You might also like to consider replacing your query and query2 that are raw SQL and use the Joomla query builder. The setQuery() will convert it to the raw SQL before it executes. It should also makes thing easier to convert if/when you moved to Joomla 4 and prepared statements. I agree with the comment by @Farid that you should try and get the complete data in a single SQL call.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions! Will do my best to get everything in one query...

Comment: You must only use answers to post the resolving advice.  Any advancements that you make that still have something wrong should be posted as an edit of the question.